# Airflow <--> Greenplum

Tags: greenplum, airflow

Is it possible to establish a connection from Airflow to Greenplum?Keeping in mind that Greenplum is based on PostgreSQL, would it be possible to establish a connection to the Greenplum master server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrea,

I think you can use Airflow to run ETLs on your analytic data within Greenplum.

The "no" answer that Jon provided was apparently in regard to using Greenplum as your backend metadata store, used internally by Airflow for keeping track of its DAGs and tasks. The code that Jon used as an example is how Airflow creates tables it uses for its backend metadata store, which has nothing to do with the contents of your Greenplum data warehouse you want to manage.

I suspect you are instead interested in Greenplum for your high-volume analytic data, not for the Airflow backend. So the answer is almost certainly yes!

You might even get by using the standard PostgreSQL hook and operator:

I say this since it appears that Greenplum can use the standard PostgreSQL Python API:
https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4330/admin_guide/managing/access_db.html

If Airflow's standard PostgreSQL hook & operator do not work for you, it is easy to create your own. See for example my work with the Snowflake data warehouse; it was a simple matter to integrate the Snowflake Python connector into airflow.

https://github.com/aberdave/airflow-snowflake

Failing all that, you should be able to use ODBC or JDBC to manage date in Greenplum via Airflow. I went with Python for my work with Snowflake, since it was so easy to customize their Python connector.

Comment: Thank you, @DaveAbercrombie. Currently trying out both methods that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

No.  A quick look at the Airflow github repo shows that they are using primary key constraints plus an additional column with a unique constraint which isn't supported in Greenplum.

For example:

```
    op.create_table(
        'user',
        sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('username', sa.String(length=250), nullable=True),
        sa.Column('email', sa.String(length=500), nullable=True),
        sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
        sa.UniqueConstraint('username')
    )
```

You can't have a primary key on (id) and another unique constraint on (username) in Greenplum.

Their github repo also doesn't have any mention of other MPP database platforms like Netezza and Teradata.  Maybe Airflow is for small data, data science but that sounds like an oxymoron.